Export suppression list from Amazon SES
Is there a way to export the list to Excel or CSV. I have been searching for hours and can't find an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78917772/1762051

I created a quick .NET app for this.
Add Nuget SimpleEmailV2.
Inside Main
        var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        
        var req = new Amazon.SimpleEmailV2.Model.ListSuppressedDestinationsRequest();
        req.PageSize = 1000;

        var resp = await client.ListSuppressedDestinationsAsync(req);

        var sList = resp.SuppressedDestinationSummaries.Select(s => new { s.EmailAddress, s.Reason, s.LastUpdateTime}).ToList();

        while(resp.NextToken  != null)
        {
            req.NextToken = resp.NextToken;
            resp = await client.ListSuppressedDestinationsAsync(req);
            sList.AddRange(resp.SuppressedDestinationSummaries.Select(s => new { s.EmailAddress, s.Reason, s.LastUpdateTime }));
        }

        CreateCSV(sList, @"path to sList.csv");

Here is your helper method to write the CSV:
    public static void CreateCSV<T>(List<T> list, string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            CreateHeader(list, sw);
            CreateRows(list, sw);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateHeader<T>(List<T> list, StreamWriter sw)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(properties[i].Name + ",");
        }
        var lastProp = properties[properties.Length - 1].Name;
        sw.Write(lastProp + sw.NewLine);
    }

    private static void CreateRows<T>(List<T> list, StreamWriter sw)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var prop = properties[i];
                sw.Write(prop.GetValue(item) + ",");
            }
            var lastProp = properties[properties.Length - 1];
            sw.Write(lastProp.GetValue(item) + sw.NewLine);
        }
    }

Note: This helper is not handling character injection that will break a CSV (i.e. quote wrapping of text that includes a quote), but it is safe here as none of the fields contain any.
Note2: I have a high level AWS access, you will need IAM access to be able to do this or you will need an access key or credentials inserted into the client.
